# How to retrieve file path location from data lake?

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am following the Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.datalake-readme?view=azure-dotnet), and it gets confusing towards the code samples, and currently i see errors with `sampleFilePath`, `SampleFileContent` that "***they dont't exist in this context"*** which they dont have documented...

```
        // Append data to the DataLake File
        file.Append(File.OpenRead(sampleFilePath), 0);
        file.Flush(SampleFileContent.Length);

        // Reading Data from a DataLake File
        Response<FileDownloadInfo> fileContents = file.Read();

        // Listing/Traversing through a DataLake Filesystem
        foreach (PathItem pathItem in filesystem.GetPaths())
        {
            names.Add(pathItem.Name);
        }
```

1. How do i get the location of the sample file path `sampleFilePath` created on the datalake?

Answer (score 0):

`sampleFilePath` is just a file path, You can create a file locally then pass file path to it. Something like this code:

```
        DataLakeFileSystemClient filesystem = serviceClient.GetFileSystemClient(Randomize("sample-filesystem"));
        filesystem.Create();

        DataLakeDirectoryClient directory = filesystem.GetDirectoryClient(Randomize("sample-file"));
        directory.Create();

        DataLakeFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(Randomize("sample-file"));
        file.Create();

        string sampleFilePath = "D:\\test\\test.txt";
        FileStream SampleFileContent = File.OpenRead(sampleFilePath);

        // Append data to the DataLake File
        file.Append(File.OpenRead(sampleFilePath), 0);
        file.Flush(SampleFileContent.Length);

        // Reading Data from a DataLake File
        Response<FileDownloadInfo> fileContents = file.Read();
```

Comment: but how do i retrieve file from DataLake? I need to pass the location of the file on the datalake into a messagequeue

Comment: @Cataster If I understand correctly, you want to get the file path which you created in Data Lake. If so, you can try this code:`file.Path + '/' + file.Name`.